# running php script featuring curl with windows task scheduler and xampp server

Tags: php, windows, curl, xampp, scheduled-tasks

I currently have a php script that uses cURL to download html source code.  I want to automate the running of this script using windows task scheduler.  I am using windows 7 along with the xampp server.  So far i have tried the following commands in windows task scheduler:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f "C:\xampp\htdocs\myscripts\myphpscript.php"
```

Task scheduler tells me the php script has run successfully but i get no results.

I have also tried the following code but get the same outcome:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -c "C:\xampp\php\php.ini" -f C:\xampp\htdocs\myscripts\myphpscript.php
```

Under normal circumstances I would run this script using the xampp shell inputting the following command:

```
php -q htdocs\myscripts\myscript.php
```

The script would then save cURLed data into the root file of my xampp server.

Many thanks in advance for help with this.

Comment: I am using php version 5.4.4 if this has any impact.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discovered the answer is to create a batch file containing the same command:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\play\bluray.php
```

I put this in the htdocs of my server and when creating the task i specified the batch file name  in the main box and entered C:\xampp\htdocs in the "start in" box.

Thanks